# Asynchronous adding to backbone model array

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I use backbone for changing my chart when my models change + require js for dependency framework. But it's problem when i update each model via ajax and push point object to value array, each sensor somehow contains points from other sensors.

I have 4 models: sensors, model definition part:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
    var Sensor = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id: undefined,
            value: undefined,
            lastTime: undefined,
            values: [], 
        }
    }
```

And I have `setInterval`, where I run function `updateAllSensors`, like:

```
updateAllSensors: function() {
    for (var sensId in this.elements.sensors) {
        var element = this.elements.sensors[sensId];
        this.updateSensor(element);
    }
    //console.log("charts");
    //this.updateAllCharts();
},

updateSensor: function(sensorModel) {
    var data = {};
    if (!sensorModel) {
        return;
    }
    var sensorId = sensorModel.get('id');
    var sensor = $('#' + sensorId);
    if (!sensor)
    return;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: sensorModel.getDbUrl(),
        success: function(data) {
            var arrayOfData = data.split(',');
            var value = parseFloat(
                arrayOfData[arrayOfData.length - 1]);
            var sensorDiv = sensor.find(".sensorVal")[0];
            sensorDiv.innerHTML = value.toFixed(1);
            var now = new Date;
            var lastTime = Date.UTC(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds(), now.getUTCMilliseconds());

            //if (sensorModel.get('values').length > 10) {
                //sensorModel.get('values').shift();
            //}
            console.log(sensorModel.get('values'));
            sensorModel.get('values').push({
                x: lastTime,
                y: value
            });
            sensorModel.set({
                'value': value,
                'lastTime': lastTime,
            });
        }
    })
},
```

And when I try to update one sensor, it puts new point into values array of my model, but when I looked into traceback I saw that VALUES arrays of all sensors are equal and contains points from all array. It means that each sensor.values array contains of all points from all sensors.

Value explanation on 4 sensors:

First running:

```
sensor1 values: 8 points (I want 1 point to sensor.values)
sensor2 values: 8 points (should be 1 point)
sensor3 values: 8 points (1 point)
sensor4 values: 8 points
```

console.log before pushing to array

sensor2

```
[]
```

sensor1

```
[{"x":1396449826635,"y":17.59441566467285},{"x":1396449826635,"y":17.59441566467285}]
```

sensor3

```
[{"x":1396449826658,"y":18.09109687805176},{"x":1396449826635,"y":17.59441566467285},
{"x":1396449826635,"y":17.59441566467285},{"x":1396449826658,"y":18.09109687805176}]
```

sensor4

```
[{"x":1396449826687,"y":17.69054794311523},{"x":1396449826658,"y":18.09109687805176},
{"x":1396449826635,"y":17.59441566467285},{"x":1396449826635,"y":17.59441566467285},
{"x":1396449826658,"y":18.09109687805176},{"x":1396449826687,"y":17.69054794311523}]
```

Second running:

```
sensor1 values: 16 points
sensor2 values: 16 points
sensor3 values: 16 points
sensor4 values: 16 points
```

Etc.

If you need fiddle I can provide, just write in comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the fiddle, can't see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `defaults` it's simply sharing the same `values` array across every instance of `Sensor`.

[From the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults):

> Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if
>   you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all
>   instances. Instead, define defaults as a function.

You need to ensure each instance of `Sensor` has a distinct array:

```
var Sensor = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: undefined,
    value: undefined,
    lastTime: undefined,
    values: function () {
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```